# How to save all words above 7 letters to a file

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a console text analysis program for an assignment.

My problem is, I need to save all user entered words above 7 letters to a text file. The user can enter words by typing in their paragraph or by loading from a text file.

Any ideas on how I can do this ?

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? How to find 7 letter words? How to read or save from/to a file?

Comment: Just how to find the 7 letter words, sorry for any confusion. I tried splitting the string then if  >=7 write to file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without giving you the code, think about what you really need to do.

1. [Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) in the entire text.
2. [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) the text based on spaces / punctuation to identify each word. This will be stored in an array.
3. Test each split string's [length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx).
4. [Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) the results to a file.

Comment: Thanks clears up my logic a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you're getting the user-entered words, but you can do a simple LINQ statement to get the words greater than 7 letters:

```
//get all words into an array (wordArray)
var bigWords = wordArray.Where(w => w.Length > 7).ToArray();
```

Then you do something with the bigWords array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to do your assignment for you.

You should check functions such as `String.Split`, `String.Length` and `String.Substring()`

Comment: Thank you, Haven't used string.substring() before so I shall do some reading